# JQuery: How can I call a function that takes two arguements multiple times, each time with different arguements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 20 folders and each folder has a set of images, some folders have only 8 pictures while others have up to 200. All folders are named from 1 to 20, and all pictures in each folder are also named by number. I want to append all the pictures from all the folders into an HTML document. This is what I have:

```
  var storedPictures = [];
  var picture, folder;
  function addPictures(x, y) {
    for(folder = 1; folder <= x; folder++);
    for(picture = 1; picture <= y; picture++) {
        storedPictures.push(
        '<img ' +
        'src="/path/to/file/' + folder + '/' +
        picture + '.jpg">'
      );
    }
```

I have other code which takes the first picture as a thumbnail and appends it at the page, when user clicks on it opens a new window with all the pictures from that set. It works for only one folder and its set, when I call the function such as this:

```
addPictures(1, 26)
```

I get all the 26 pictures from folder 1. But I want all the pictures from all the folders, and simply writing the call multiple times doesn't work:

```
addPictures(1, 26)
addPictures(2, 10)
addPictures(3, 36)
```

And like that I only get the set that I called first (1, 26).

I am novice at javascript so my details probably don't make enough sense, so please do tell me what other detail I should give. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your example. First is, the addPictures function misses closing bracket. I suppose that is a copy paste error.

The other, folder loop, is a lot harder to spot: `for(folder = 1; folder <= x; folder++);`

Because of the semicolon `;`, the loop is running empty. Try doing `for(folder = 1; folder <= x; folder++) console.log(folder); console.log(folder)`.

What happens is that when you set your `x` to for example `3`, the folder loops increments folder from 1 to 3 (actually, by getting outside of the loop it gets to 4). This behavior does not really happen for `x==1` because `folder++` never gets executed.

Because of this, when you call `addPictures(2, 10)`, you are adding pictures number 1 to 10 from folder 3 instead of 2.

Removing the semicolon from that loop will give a more reasonable output. However, I am still not sure, it is a desired output. If you remove the semicolon, `addPictures(2, 10)` will actually add pictures 1 to 10 from directory 2, but it will get pictures 1 to 10 from directory 1 too. It is because the first iteration will hold `folder=1` and only the second iteration will have `folder=2`. `addPictures(3,36) would try to load pictures 1 to 36 from directory 1, 2 and 3.

Therefore I guess what you want is:

```
 function addPictures(folder, maxPicNumber) {
    for(picture = 1; picture <= maxPicNumber; picture++) {
        storedPictures.push(
        '<img ' +
        'src="/path/to/file/' + folder + '/' +
        picture + '.jpg">'
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What your function is trying to do is to take **y** picture(s) form **x** folder(s) . If that is the case, you can use this function

```
var storedPictures = [];

  function addPictures(x, y) {
    for(var folder = 1; folder <= x; folder++) {
     for(var picture = 1; picture <= y; picture++) {
        storedPictures.push(
         '<img ' +
         'src="/path/to/file/' + folder + '/' +
         picture + '.jpg">'
        );
     }
    //console.log(storedPictures); //print the result to console
   }
  }
  addPictures(2,20);
```